# 1 nginx server multiple php servers

Tags: nginx, cluster-computing

what i am missing?
lets say this simple conf:

```
upstream php {
  server 111.1111.1111.1111:9000;
}
server {
    listen 80 reuseport;


    root /var/www/html/public/;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        set $orig_uri $uri;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        ssi on;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $orig_uri$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$orig_uri$is_args$args";
        add_header X-Cache-Key $scheme$request_method$orig_uri$is_args$args;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        }
}
```

how does nginx gonna access "/var/www/html/public/" on different server? how will it know if the file exists or not exists? I tried to play with it and I always get

> 404 Not Found

So i am missing something but cant understand what, if the php servers dont have nginx installed

Comment: You're not specifying here that nginx should try serving files on it's own. Theoretically it will just pass request to phpfpm daemon in case query string ends with `.php`. Which url did not work for you?

Comment: this config already work when nginx and php are on same server anyway I try with and without .php same 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does nginx gonna access "/var/www/html/public/" on different
>   server? how will it know if the file exists or not exists?

`nginx` cannot determine if the file exists on the upstream PHP service. It will pass a script pathname to the PHP service and if it does not exist, the PHP service will return a 404 response.

The PHP service probably uses the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter to find the upstream script file. The parameter should be defined in your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file.

This is usually set to a value of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`. The value for `$document_root` being set by the `root` directive in your configuration file.

This will only work if the scripts on the upstream server are placed in the exact same directory hierarchy as specified by the `nginx` server. Otherwise, you may need to handcraft the value of the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter.

Comment: thanks, if I surf to <php-fpm-server-ip>:9000 I should see the website? cuz its returning 502 so I can debug where the problem is

Comment: You should **not** be able to surf to it. It uses the FastCGI protocol and not the HTTP protocol.